# Pass SQL query result to stored procedure parameter

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL query which returns a result in `varchar`, then I am trying to pass that result to a stored procedure parameter, but I am getting an error

> Must declare the scalar variable "@datev"

SQL :

```sql
DECLARE @datev varchar

SELECT
    CONVERT(varchar, (CASE
                         WHEN DATENAME (dw, GETDATE()) IN ('Thursday') 
                            THEN CONVERT (varchar, DATEADD(d, -6, GETDATE()), 112)
                         WHEN DATENAME (dw, GETDATE()) IN ('Friday') 
                            THEN CONVERT (varchar, DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE()), 112) 
                         WHEN DATENAME (dw, GETDATE()) IN ('Saturday') 
                            THEN CONVERT (varchar, DATEADD(d, -8, GETDATE()), 112)
                         WHEN DATENAME (dw, GETDATE()) IN ('Sunday') 
                            THEN CONVERT (varchar, DATEADD(d, -9, GETDATE()), 112)
                         ELSE CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(d, -((DATEPART (weekday, GETDATE()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 14), GETDATE()), 112) 
                      END), 112) AS rptdate 
INTO 
    #rwed

SELECT rptdate FROM #rwed

SELECT @datev = rptdate FROM #rwed
```

Procedure want to call:

```
EXEC Product_Movemnet1 @datev
```

Comment: If those statements in the same batch, they won't generate that error. Are they in separate batches?

Comment: Also [Bad Habits to Kick : Declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length). Your dates are going to fit in a `varchar(1)`.

Comment: Why are you converting dates to a `vachar` to pass as a parameter anyway? Use a strongly typed date and time data type.

Comment: Several things are flawed with your approach, already there's the incorrect use of `varchar`, another is that return values from a procedure are `integers` only, suggest you read up on [output parameters](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-stored-procedures/stored-procedure-output-parameters/)

Comment: I suspect by "returns" the OP does not mean `RETURN` , @Stu .

Comment: It would help if the OP could post the complete procedure and use-case - and should that be `Product_Movement1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An explanation for almost anything is available in the documentation if you know where to look. I guess that is what search engines are for :-)

### Batches

In order to reproduce that error I have to assume that your are running both your queries in two **different batches**:

1. `DECLARE @datev varchar ...`
2. `EXEC Product_Movemnet1 @datev`

### Defining a batch

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to query your Microsoft SQL Server database, then the **scope of the batch** can be defined multiple ways:

1. By the query window: by default all SQL statements in one query window make up one batch.
2. By adding `GO` statements between your queries allows you to group queries and define separate batches.
   [`GO` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/sql-server-utilities-statements-go) extract:

> GO signals the end of a batch of Transact-SQL statements to the SQL Server utilities.

3. By selecting only a section of the SQL statements in the query window.
   [SSMS shortcuts documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-keyboard-shortcuts) extract:

> Run the selected portion of the query editor or the entire query editor if nothing is selected

### Variables

What does batch scope have to do with the error from your question? Well, the `@datev` from your code is called a variable. An the way you defined it, makes it a **local variable**.

[Variables documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/variables-transact-sql) extract:

> A Transact-SQL local variable is an object that can hold a single data value of a specific type.

Reading up on the `DECLARE` syntax for variables then explains your error.

[`DECLARE` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql#remarks) extract:

> The scope of a local variable is the batch in which it is declared.

In other words: a local variable only exists during the lifetime of a single SQL statement batch.

### Summary

Executing the statements that declare your variable, set your variable and use your variable in one batch, resolves the error.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=06a740e72f8eb02a05f3a421bd22128e) to see the error reproduced and solved.

---

### Remark

Your current solution will probably not produce the result you are after (see remarks in the question comments about the data type `varchar` without specifying length). Also, it can be shortened a bit:

```
-- attempt at improved version
-- + replace "varchar" with "varchar(10)"
-- + remove use of temporary table #rwed
-- + convert to string _once_
-- + replace "IN" with "=" for list with only one item

DECLARE @datev varchar(10);

SELECT @datev = CONVERT(varchar(10),
                   (CASE WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Thursday' THEN DATEADD(d, -6, GETDATE())
                         WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Friday'   THEN DATEADD(d, -7, GETDATE()) 
                         WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Saturday' THEN DATEADD(d, -8, GETDATE())
                         WHEN DATENAME(dw, GETDATE()) = 'Sunday'   THEN DATEADD(d, -9, GETDATE())
                         ELSE DATEADD(d, -((DATEPART (weekday, GETDATE()) + 1 + @@DATEFIRST) % 14), GETDATE())
                      END), 112);

EXEC Product_Movement1 @datev;
```